# How to filter NA values and add it to a new DataFrame

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have an input dataset in .csv format which I am trying to input in python and do some data analysis. The sample format is given below:

```
col1   col2   col3   col4   col5
 1      0      0      1      NA
 2      3      5      1      NA
 1      1      4      6      NA
 7      8      9      1      1 
 12     13     0      34     5
 4      5      6      1      2
```

Here if you see, column 5 has NA values. I need to filter this NA values alone, so that all the rows that ha NA values should be removed from this dataframe and copied into new dataframe, so that the resulting dataframe should be as below:

Dataframe With NA Values:

```
   col1   col2   col3   col4   col5
    1      0      0      1      NA
    2      3      5      1      NA
    1      1      4      6      NA
```

DataFrame without NA Values:

```
    col1   col2   col3   col4   col5
     7      8      9      1      1 
     12     13     0      34     5
     4      5      6      1      2
```

I should get two dataframes as mentioned above, that will be used in my further analysis. I am looking for python - pandas code, to implement these methods programatically. Could someone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that after reading it in, your col5 contains real NaNs and not the string NA, you could simply use whether or not they're null to select from `df`:

```
>>> key = df["col5"].isnull()
>>> df_NA = df.loc[key]
>>> df_notNA = df.loc[~key]
>>> df_NA
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
0     1     0     0     1   NaN
1     2     3     5     1   NaN
2     1     1     4     6   NaN
>>> df_notNA
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
3     7     8     9     1   1.0
4    12    13     0    34   5.0
5     4     5     6     1   2.0
```

Alternatively, you could use `groupby`, which might be overkill here but works nicely when there are more cases to consider than merely two:

```
>>> dfs = dict(list(df.groupby(df["col5"].isnull())))
>>> dfs[False]
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
3     7     8     9     1   1.0
4    12    13     0    34   5.0
5     4     5     6     1   2.0
>>> dfs[True]
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
0     1     0     0     1   NaN
1     2     3     5     1   NaN
2     1     1     4     6   NaN
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I am exactly looking for. It worked. Also I have noted your point regarding image upload and will keep that in mind for future posts. Thanks again.

Comment: Now I have some values updated for Nan and now I need to put the newly updated Col5 values in the same order as earlier. Example: If my NaN Values are as below:

Comment: @Srinath: if you have a new question, ask a new question.  Don't add stuff to the comments on an answer to an old question.